# Why is my "Submit" button remaining DISABLED?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have a form containing 2 radio-buttons. And, at the bottom of the form is a "Submit" button.

One button is to choose Paypal as a form of payment; the other button is to choose Credit Card.

I wrote a script to "disable" the submit, unless one of the radio buttons is selected.

For some reason, my "Submit" button remains **disabled**.  ((

Here is my script :

```
  <script   
  src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'> 
  </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function displayForm(c) {
            if (c.value == "2") {    
                jQuery('#paypalformContainer').toggle('show');
                jQuery('#ccformContainer').hide();
                if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked==true)
                {
                document.getElementById('radio1').checked=false;
                }

            }
                if (c.value == "1") {
                    if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked==true)
                    {
                    document.getElementById('radio2').checked=false;
                    }
                 jQuery('#ccformContainer').toggle('show');
                 jQuery('#paypalformContainer').hide();
            }
        };
        </script>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fCheck() { 
            var x = document.getElementById('radio1').value;
            var x2 = document.getElementById('radio2').value;
            if (x==null || x=="") {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;
                } else { if (x2==null || x2=="") {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true; } else {   
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false; } } }
        </script>
```

And here is the form itself :

```
 <form name="topup" id="topup" method="post" action="top_up">
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" id="radio1"   
 onClick="displayForm(this),fCheck()"></input>Via Credit Card<br><br>
            <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" id="radio2" 
 onClick="displayForm(this),fCheck()"></input>Via Paypal
            <div style="display:none" id="ccformContainer">
            <br>
                <form id="ccform"> 
                <label>Enter your credit card details :  </label>
                <br>
                <br>
                <dd>
                    <p>Credit Card Name :
            <input type="text" id="ccname" name="ccname" value="$ccname">
        </p>
        <p>Credit Card Type :
            <select name="cctype" required>
                <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                <option value="American Express">American Express</option>
                <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
                <option value="Diners Club">Diners Club</option>
                <option value="Maestro">Maestro</option>
                <option value="Verified By Visa">Verified By Visa</option>
                <option value="Visa Electron">Visa Electron</option>
            </select>
            <p>Credit Card Number :
                <input type="text" minlength="16" id="ccnumber" 
      name="ccnumber" value="$ccnumber">
            </p>
            <p>Credit Expiry Date : Month :
                <select name="ccexpdatemonth" required>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select> <span>Year : <select name="ccexpdateyear" 
    required>
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    </select></span>
                <p>Credit Card CVC :
                    <input type="text" minlength="3" id="cccvc" name="cccvc" 
     value="$cccvc">
                </p>
            </dd>
            </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div style="display:none" id="paypalformContainer">
                <form id="paypalform">
                <label>Enter your Paypal Details  :</label>
                <dd>Paypal Address :
                    <input type="text" id="paypal" name="paypal"  
          value="$paypal">
                </dd>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" 
       name="submit" id="submit" value="Pay Here" disabled></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Radio button becomes enabled in Chrome v43.0.2357.130 m

Comment: Hmm, your code works as intended for me in chrome and IE, so I have no idea what could be going wrong. Also, checking the radio buttons and dechecking the other seems redundant, since both buttons are in the same radio button group, the other radio gets disabled automatically.

Comment: Scott :  you mean by version of Chrome is outdated?

Comment: Maybe try $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled'); ?

Comment: @phpnewbie2015 No, I'm saying that the code you have provided worked perfectly well when tested in Chrome v43.0.2357.130m. Be aware though, you have multiple validation errors including unclosed tags, incorrect element attributes and you should not nest your `<form>` elements either. I haven't posted an answer which includes these fixes since your `<button>` seems to be behaving appropriately.